# mysql init-file config option giving file not found error

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apparmor

I want to have a SQL script run whenever mysql starts but I can't get it working in Ubuntu 11.10.

I added a "[init-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file)" option to the mysql config file:

```
> sudo emacs -nw /etc/mysql/my.cnf
...
[mysqld]
init-file=/etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql
...
```

But when I restart mysql, it fails with a "*File not found*" error:

```
> tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
111111  7:41:06 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql' not found (Errcode: 13)
111111  7:41:06 [ERROR] Aborting
```

But the file certainly exists and is readable:

```
> ls -l /etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 30 2011-11-09 05:06 /etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Is this a Ubuntu oddness or did I do something dumb?

---

Info:

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and MySQL 5.1.

```
> mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.1.58-1ubuntu1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Comment: What is the output of `file /etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql`?

Comment: `file /etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql` gives "/etc/mysql/mysqlinit.sql: ASCII text, with no line terminators"

Comment: To narrow down the problem, just try to move it to `/tmp` folder to see what happens. Are you running AppArmor?

Comment: I tried using a init-file in `/tmp` but no luck. Yes, I think Ubuntu uses AppArmor.

Comment: If so, try to stop AppArmor and see if the error go away.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks @quanta, the problem was indeed apparmor.

To fix the issue:

Edit the mysql apparmor file:

> sudo emacs -nw /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

Include the folder where your init-file lives with the *.sql extension:

```
...
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
    /var/log/mysql.log rw,
    /var/log/mysql.err rw,
    ;/var/lib/mysql/ r,
    /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
    /var/log/mysql/ r,
    /var/log/mysql/* rw,
    /{,var/}run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
    /{,var/}run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,

    /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,

    # I added to allow my init-file script to run
    /etc/mysql/*.sql r,
}
```

And then make AppArmor reload the profiles.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

Then reload mysql:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Now the init-file gets executed. Yay!